# Pyhton split XML file and store in a CSV file

Tags: python, xml, csv

I want to convert an XML file to CSV, the full file is [here](https://donnees.roulez-eco.fr/opendata/jour).  Here's a sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<pdv_liste>
    <pdv id="1000013" latitude="4619851.83794" longitude="524350.637881" cp="01000" pop="R">
        <adresse>BOULEVARD CHARLES DE GAULLE</adresse>
        <ville>Bourg-en-Bresse</ville>
        <horaires automate-24-24="">
            <jour id="1" nom="Lundi" ferme="" />
            <jour id="2" nom="Mardi" ferme="" />
            <jour id="3" nom="Mercredi" ferme="" />
            <jour id="4" nom="Jeudi" ferme="" />
            <jour id="5" nom="Vendredi" ferme="" />
            <jour id="6" nom="Samedi" ferme="" />
            <jour id="7" nom="Dimanche" ferme="" />
        </horaires>
        <services>
            <service>Carburant additivé</service>
            <service>DAB (Distributeur automatique de billets)</service>
        </services>
        <prix nom="Gazole" id="1" maj="2023-03-09T00:01:00" valeur="1.805" />
        <prix nom="E10" id="5" maj="2023-03-09T00:01:00" valeur="1.843" />
        <prix nom="SP98" id="6" maj="2023-03-09T00:01:00" valeur="1.919" />
        <rupture id="2" nom="SP95" debut="2022-09-27T09:15:21" fin="" />
        <rupture id="3" nom="E85" debut="2022-09-27T09:15:21" fin="" />
        <rupture id="4" nom="GPLc" debut="2022-09-27T09:15:22" fin="" />
    </pdv>
</pdv_liste>
```

Below is the Pyhton code that I use, though an error is returned.

```
    row['debut'] = rupture.attrib['debut']
KeyError: 'debut'
```

I don't understand this error as I have followed the strucure of the XML.
Furthermore, if I remove the lines referring to `debut` to see if there is another problem, the data returned in the CSV and those in the XML do nor correspond.

i.e. in the CSV, data should be returned in the column `'rupture_nom'` corresponding to `id : 1000001` as we can see in the XML.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

# Define the data fields to extract
fields = ['pdv_id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'cp', 'pop',
          'adresse',
          'ville',
          'jour_nom', 'ferme',
          'prix_nom', 'valeur',
          'rupture_nom', 'debut', 'fin']

# Create a new CSV file and add the header row
with open('pdv_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()

    # Parse the XML file and extract the data fields
    tree = ET.parse('PrixCarburants_quotidien_20230309.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for pdv in root.iter('pdv'):
        row = {
            'pdv_id': pdv.attrib['id'],
            'latitude': pdv.attrib['latitude'],
            'longitude': pdv.attrib['longitude'],
            'cp': pdv.attrib['cp'],
            'pop': pdv.attrib['pop'],
            'adresse': pdv.find('adresse').text,
            'ville': pdv.find('ville').text
        }

        # Extract jour data and append to row
        for jour in pdv.iter('jour'):
            row['jour_nom'] = jour.attrib['nom']
            row['ferme'] = jour.attrib['ferme']
            writer.writerow(row)

        # Extract prix data and append to row
        for prix in pdv.iter('prix'):
            row['prix_nom'] = prix.attrib['nom']
            row['valeur'] = prix.attrib['valeur']
            writer.writerow(row)
        
        # Extract rupture data and append to row
        for rupture in pdv.iter('prix'):
            row['rupture_nom'] = rupture.attrib['nom']
            row['debut'] = rupture.attrib['debut']
            row['fin'] = rupture.attrib['fin']
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `for rupture in pdv.iter('rupture')` and not `for rupture in pdv.iter('prix')`

Comment: I added a sample of the XML that contains jour, prix, and rupture. Please edit your question and add the (hand-coded) CSV you expect to be able to produce from that specific sample. And, yeah, like @Tranbi pointed out, you iterate prix a second time but try to access attributes that only exist on rupture, so you get that Key Error. Also, despite the file explicitly declaring it is ISO-8859-1, chardetect and VS Code both think **it's Windows-1252**. As 8859-1, the "é" in "Carburant additivé" (from the sample above) does not decode properly, it decodes properly with 1252.

Comment: Going back to your unexpected result, can you say what the code is doing right now? I see that it iterates all the jours writing separate rows for those, then it iterates all the prixs writing separate rows (with the values from **the last jour**), then it iterates all the ruptures writing separate rows (with the values from the last jour **and the last prix**). For the sample XML above, 7 jours + 3 prixs + 3 ruptures = [13 rows](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/f3688f6bc23023cbb8b0ad9f12f3b9cf#file-output-csv). How you expect to aggregate those values? A sample CSV will help us all.

Answer (score 0):

This csv is ISO8859-1 encoded:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml("PrixCarburants_quotidien_20230309.xml", xpath=".//rupture", encoding='iso-8859-1')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       id     nom                debut  fin
0       3     E85  2017-09-16T09:50:23  NaN
1       4    GPLc  2017-09-16T09:50:23  NaN
2       5     E10  2018-12-13T09:49:49  NaN
3       2    SP95  2023-01-27T12:34:37  NaN
4       1  Gazole  2023-01-27T12:34:37  NaN
...    ..     ...                  ...  ...
24109   4    GPLc  2018-06-13T08:01:49  NaN
24110   2    SP95  2022-12-13T14:29:26  NaN
24111   4    GPLc  2022-12-13T14:29:26  NaN
24112   1  Gazole  2013-12-07T00:00:00  NaN
24113   2    SP95  2014-01-12T00:00:00  NaN
```

But the failure in your code; debut is an **attribute from `<rupture>` tag** and will not found under *`<prixe>`* loop!